# Declare type of a struct field by type of another struct field

Tags: go, struct, types, field

Here is *s3.GetObjectOutput struct:

```
type GetObjectOutput struct {
    ...
    Metadata map[string]*string
    ...
}
```

I want to declare my struct with a struct field has type of Metadata field in GetObjectOutput struct like this

```
type MyObject struct {
    Metadata *s3.GetObjectOutput.Metadata
    ...
}
```

But it was not correct. How do I declare a struct with a field has type of another struct's field instead of explicitly write down:

```
type MyObject struct {
    Metadata map[string]*string
    ...
}
```

Comment: You cannot. The only way it to copy the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@William Poussier
In that way I have to use a global variable just for use its type. As @zerkms suggested I copied Metadata type from *s3.GetObjectOutput

```
type Metadata map[string]*string
```

and use:

```
type MyObject struct { 
    Metadata
}
```

Comment: Why do you embed it then ? Btw a new answer if not the best place to answer my own answer, use the comments.

Comment: @WilliamPoussier I want to use only the type of Metadata in *s3.GetObjectOutput struct. If I embed *s3.GetObjectOutput, it will pollute my MyObject struct. And since I want to clearly declare field of MyObject struct as Metadata type, not map[string]*string type, I embedded Metadata type in MyObject struct

Answer (score 1):

As @zerkms said, you can't.
Best idea is to probably create your own field of the same type in `MyObject`.

You can also embed the `s3.GetObjectOutput` in `MyObject`.

```
type MyObject struct {
    *s3.GetObjectOutput
    ...
}
```

Given `myobj` is an instance of `MyObject`, use `myobj.Metadata`.